# Labeling an object by number

Tags: object, labeling

I want to label values of a column (Address) that has object dtype with number. the number that is to be labeled  is average of two columns(Area and price).
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqEd.png)

if we convert them to separate series, it can be possible answer? how can I do this for every row?